# Which registry keys are used by office365 Business Premium?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry, office365, group-policy

after migration from Office2016 to O365 Business Standard we realized, that our GPOs partly stopped working. Some googleFU gave the hint, that we´d need at least E3 Plan for those we used the admx templates to work again. Some older GPOs used direct Registry manipulation.

Because some of the old Policies still worked, I started digging into the Registry and found, that everything in
[HKCU]Software\Microsoft\Policies has no effect.
There are some Keys in
[HKCU]Software\Microsoft\Office
though, that still had an effect.

For example
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings]
"DisableSignatures"=dword:00000001
had previously greyed out the Signature field.
Now, with O365, you´re able to click "Signature" and then Outlook crashes.

Stuff like
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\ProtectedView]
Does even work as expected.

Is there any (unofficial) documentation for those none-Policies keys?

Thanks for help